# Symfony2 OOP design

Tags: symfony, oop

I'm facing a OOP design problem ... My goal is to build a Improvement system.
It is really simple to understand, here is the code sample :

```
<?php 

interface Improvement {
    public function getGains();
    public function isActivated();
}

// tagged "improvement"
class AImprovement implements Improvement {

    public function getGains() {
        return 1;
    }

    public function isActivated() {
        return true;
    }

}

// tagged "improvement"
class BImprovement implements Improvement  {

    private $statsCenter;

    public function __construct(StatsCenter $statsCenter) {
        $this->statsCenter = $statsCenter;
    }

    public function getGains() {
        return 10;
    }

    public function isActivated() {
        return $statsCenter->getStats()['totalGains'] > 10;
    }

}

class ImprovementCenter {

    private $improvements;

    public function addImprovement(Improvement $improvement) {
        $this->improvements[] = $improvement;
    }

    public funtion getGainsSum() {
        $s = 0;
        foreach ($this->improvements as $improvement) {
            $s += $improvement->getGains();
        }
        return $s;
    }

}

class StatsCenter {

    private $improvementCenter;

    public function __construct(ImprovementCenter $improvementCenter) {

        $this->improvementCenter = $improvementCenter;

    }

    public function getStats() {

        return [
            'totalGains' => Money::toEUR($this->improvementCenter->getGainsSum())
        ];

    }

}
```

We can create **x** implementations of `Improvement` interface. If we tag them with "improvement" they will be added to the definition of `ImprovementCenter` with addMethodCall by calling `addImprovement`.
So, `ImprovementCenter` has a clear dependency on all the "improvement" tagged services.
And for some reason `BImprovement` is enabled only if the gains in euros > 10. ( Don't ask me why ).

But we can clearly see a circular dependency : `BImprovement` -> `StatsCenter` -> `ImprovementCenter` -> `BImprovement` ...

Any ideas on how to solve it ? (I already found some solution but I need more ideas). The side goal is also to benefits lazy services loading of symfony2, ImprovementCenter must be created only if it is injected somewhere.

Thank you !

EDIT : 
Here is one dirty solution that I found. First the main problem is that here I have an observer pattern with `Improvement`s as Observers. The consequence is that `ImprovementCenter` (the subject) depends on all its observers, that is not the pattern goal.

Then I moved the dependencies: I have kind of an `ObserverManager` that depends on `ImprovementCenter` and all `Improvent`s, the `ObserverManager` manually do `$improvementCenter->addImprovement($improvement)`.
Now the `$improvementCenter` has no dependency on `Improvement`s.
The problem is that I must initialise `ObserverManager` on each `kernelRequest`, without that trick the `ImprovementCenter` will not have any `Improvement`s linked as observers. 
This solution perfectly works, but it smells kind of bad .. ahah

Ideas ?

Comment: The only way i see to eliminate the circular reference is to make the improvements order dependent. In this way I would use a decorator pattern to improvements and make all decision based on previous improvements. With this approach the class improvementcenter would no longer exist and stascenter could receive a improvement in getstats.